# Facebook PHP SDK login error "Cross-site request forgery validation failed" ONLY PHP 7.2

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, codeigniter-3, php-7.2

I need some insight from someone who had a similar issue or has any grasp on what might be going on here.
My config:

```
Codeigniter 3.0.6
"facebook/graph-sdk" : "version": "5.6.2"
facebook-sdk-v4-codeigniter  @version     3.0.0
$config['facebook_graph_version']       = 'v2.12';
server: nginx with php fpm v7.0
```

Everything worked great until I tried upgrading to PHP 7.2. After upgrade login process fails with endless redirect loop. This loops is caused by website not being able to authenticate, I tracked the error to this:

"Cross-site request forgery validation failed. Required param "state" missing from persistent data."

As soon as I switch back to using fpm v7.0 all is working fine again.
State GET parameter is still in the url and still is accessible in codeigniter. Any ideas?

**SOLUTION: update CI to 3.1.9**

Comment: _“State GET parameter is still in the url”_ - the error message does not complain about it not being found in there, but in the persistent data … The value of the GET parameter gets compared to the value stored in the _session_, and apparently it isn’t in the session. So go check that your session is working correctly in the first place.

Comment: Ok, then it probably is session related. However sessions are controlled through Codeigniter and they are managed in mysql table. They work completely fine in 7.2 as long as I am using Codeigniter session functions. I assume graph api uses default session handler, but I don't see any errors related to not being able to start session and why would it stop working by simply using a newer php version? Php config is default in both cases.

Comment: Does that still happen transparently via $_SESSION, or is CI providing its own objects and methods for session handling here? If the latter, you might need to implement your own PersistentDataInterface to properly wrap the CI functionality, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/PersistentDataInterface/

Comment: _“don't see any errors related to not being able to start session”_ - it might simply not be able to pick up the session again, so that a new session id is generated. _“and why would it stop working by simply using a newer php version?”_ - couldn’t tell you that, not that familiar with CI’s session handling …

Comment: yes, session handling was the problem, it was only fine when using CI functions. I managed to update CI to 3.1.9 and it actually helped. Not in the mood to look for a root cause. Thanks for the hint to check sessions!